# Programmatically disable specific PHP functions for testing

Tags: php

I have a function that makes HTTP requests with cURL that falls back to `file_get_contents()` if cURL is not available on the system.

I would like to write unit tests for this function (utilizing PHPUnit) where cURL is available for some tests, and not available for others.

**Is it possible to programmatically disable PHP functions, such as `curl_init()`?**

I know I can use the `disable_functions` setting in php.ini, but I was hoping to find a way to do unit tests without reconfiguring PHP in between runs.

Comment: Does `ini_set('disable_functions', '...');` work?

Comment: @Crozin, No, `disable_functions` is only available for php.ini.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`runkit_function_remove`](http://php.net/runkit_function_remove) to remove any defined function, I think:

```
runkit_function_remove('curl_init');
```

And, as per the documentation:

> **Note:** By default, only userspace functions may be removed, renamed, or modified. In order to override internal functions, you must enable the `runkit.internal_override` setting in `php.ini`.

Comment: That will work, thanks!  I don't have runkit currently installed, but I will snag it in a bit.