# How to enable cURL programmatically?

Tags: php, curl, php-extension

I know the manual process uncomment the line

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

But I need this enable using php code.
any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for [`runkit_function_add()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-add.php)

```
runkit_function_add('curl_init');
```

This is the opposite of what this user is trying to do in this thread: 
[Programmatically disable specific PHP functions for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380423/programmatically-disable-specific-php-functions-for-testing)

Answer (score 1):

<s>This can only be done in the `php.ini` file.</s>

Edit: Apparently it can be done as the original poster stated.